# Angular 2 - using component variables inside inner function

Tags: javascript, angular

Assuming I have the following function:

```
ifvisible.now("idle", function(){
            // Stop auto updating the live data
            if (this.activitySub)
            this.activitySub.unsubscribe();
            });
```

Since all the variables inside `function() { }` are not recognized, how I can import or use them inside the function (or in any other way)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this `Arrow Functions`, not tested but may work for you :-

```
ifvisible.now("idle", () => {
  ...your code...
});
```

by using Arrow Functions

- You don't need to keep typing function
- It lexically captures the meaning of this
- It lexically captures the meaning of arguments

see also

- https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/arrow-functions.html